# systemd service error: no route to host after booting

Tags: networking, routing, systemd

I want my computer telnet to a remote machine (directly connected with Ethernet) when booting.
I add `feedback.service` under `/etc/systemd/system/`

```
[Unit]
Description=Feedback relay daemon
Wants=network-online.target network.target
After=network-online.target network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/feedback.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

feeback.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
telnet 192.180.0.60 9000
exit 0
```

I used the option `After=network-online.target` to make sure this script would run after network configuration was done.
However, `systemctl status feedback` still show `No route to host` error after reboot.
It seems routing table was not set well at the moment `feedback.sh` was activated.

I already checked remote host is up and the network is accessible.
I can `ping` remote host after reboot finished.
I tried to add `sleep 10` at top of the script then it worked well.

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10
telnet 192.180.0.60 9000
exit 0
```

But it's just a workaround. I need a real solution.

====================2019/08/22 Update============================

```
root@host# systemctl list-dependencies network-online.target
network-online.target
● └─networking.service
```

Comment: What are you using to configure the network, NetworkManager or systemd-networkd or something else? What's the output of `systemctl list-dependencies network-online.target`?

Comment: I use `/etc/network/interface` to config my internet
`systemctl list-dependencies network-online.target`
shows `networking.service`